# Invalid Filename in PrintManager.PrintToFileName

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am having an issue with the Revit API PrintManager properties, in particular with the PrintToFileName property and the error: *Invalid fileName*.

What is the proper way to declare what you wish for a printed view to be named when printing to pdf?

My Source (Puts a schedule onto an empty sheet and prints it):

```
ViewSheet sheet = ViewSheet.Create(Doc, ElementId.InvalidElementId);
Element view = new FilteredElementCollector(Doc)
    .OfClass(typeof(ViewSchedule))
    .Where(o => o.Name == element) //element is a string from a list of items in a WPF listbox.
    .First();

ScheduleSheetInstance.Create(Doc, sheet.Id, view.Id, XYZ.Zero);
ViewSet set = new ViewSet();
set.Insert(sheet);


IList<ElementId> print = new List<ElementId>();
print.Add(sheet.Id);
Uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(print);
printManager.PrintRange = PrintRange.Select;
ViewSheetSetting viewSheetSetting = printManager.ViewSheetSetting;
viewSheetSetting.CurrentViewSheetSet.Views = set;

printManager.SelectNewPrintDriver("Adobe PDF");
printManager.PrintToFile = true;
printManager.CombinedFile = true;
printManager.PrintToFileName = "TestFileName"; //ERROR HERE

printManager.Apply();
printManager.SubmitPrint(sheet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found the problem in my formatting thanks to Bogdans post as well as [This comment](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/printing-api-and-printmanager-printtofilename-setting/m-p/9102218/highlight/true#M42080) on the Autodesk Revit Api Forum.

Turns out, the PrintToFileName calls for both a *path* and a *filename* string. Working snippet is as follows:

```
                    string path = @"[same file path here ]";
                    string currentViewName = view.Name;
                    printManager.PrintToFileName = path + currentViewName + ".pdf";
                    printManager.Apply();
```

Thanks for the response, Bogdan.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to input the full path + name of the file to work.